# Importing File WIth Field Terminators In Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bcp, import-from-csv

I've been given some csv files that I want to turn into tables in a SQL database. However, the genius who created the files used comma delimiters, even though several data fields contain commas. So when I try to BCP the data into the database, I get a whole bunch of errors.

Is there a way that I can escape the commas that aren't field separators? At the moment I'm tempted to write a script to manually replace every comma in each file with a pipe, and then go through and manually change the affected rows back.

Comment: Without field identifiers/text qualifiers?  No, that's not possible.  SQL Server (BCP, import wizard, SSIS) is extremely picky about such things, and will just throw an error if it doesn't see exactly what it expects.  If you can't get a corrected file, you'll need to manually make the corrections.

Comment: You can't escape the commas, and even if you could how would you differentiate delimiter commas from literal commas? What you really need is to have the fields with commas surrounded by quotes. If possible I'd ask the genius to put quotes around all fields (and find another line of work). I'm afraid any fix you do with the existing file will be highly manual no matter how you approach it.

Comment: I ended up writing a script that replaces all the commas wit pipes, and logs lines where the number of pipes is greater than it should be, so I can go through and change those manually.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this is to write a script or program that fixes the data.

If the bad data is limited to a single field the process should be trivial:
You consume the row from either side by the count of good delimiters and replace with a new unique delimiter and what remains is the column with the extra old delimiters that you would just leave as is.

If you have two bad fields straddling good fields, you would need some kind of advanced logic, for instance I had XML data with delimiters, I had to parse the XML until I found a terminating tag and then process the other delimiters as needed.